# failed job docker deploy - gitlab CI pipelines

Tags: windows, docker

An error occurs : ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1 in the phase docker-deploy

stages:

- build
- docker-build
- docker-deploy

variables:
TAG_LATEST: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:latest
TAG_COMMIT: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

build:
stage: build
image: node
script:
- echo ""Start building App""
- ls
- npm --version
- node --version
- curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
- . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
- nvm --version
- nvm install 14.16.1
- node --version
- rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json
- npm install
- pwd
- ls
- CI=false npm run-script build
- pwd
- ls
- echo ""Build successfully!""
artifacts:
expire_in: 1 hour
paths:
- build
- node_modules

docker-build:
stage: docker-build
image: docker:20.10.22
services:
- name: docker:19.03.8-dind
before_script:
- pwd
- docker login -u ""$CI_REGISTRY_USER"" -p ""$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"" $CI_REGISTRY
- apk update && apk add bash
- apk add --update curl && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
- curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.36.0/install.sh | bash
- . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
- nvm --version
- whoami
- ls
- pwd
script:
- pwd
- ls
- docker build --pull -t ""$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"" -t $TAG_COMMIT -t $TAG_LATEST .
- docker push ""$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE""
- docker push $TAG_COMMIT
- docker push $TAG_LATEST
- pwd

docker-deploy:
stage: docker-deploy
image: docker:20.10.22
before_script:
- echo ""deploying app""
script:
- chmod og= $ID_RSA
- apk update && apk add openssh-client
- ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP ""docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY""
- ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP ""docker pull $TAG_COMMIT""
#- ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP ""docker container rm -f projet_name || true""
- ssh -i $ID_RSA -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP ""docker run -d -p 86:80 --name hirelands $TAG_COMMIT""

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.